UiPath Studio Web Microsoft OneDrive & SharePoint Connection Failed
I'm running the UiPath Studio Web example template "Table Data Extraction for Sales Opportunities to Excel workbook"  and at the step of [Microsoft OneDrive & SharePoint connection]  I got a run-time error with the error message "Invalid shares key". 
What does this error mean and how can I resolve this error? 
(There was no problem establishing connection with OneDrive with my microsoft account)

